# PHP Pass by Reference Issue

Tags: php, variables, reference

So I am having a strange issue where the functions are NOT defined by pass by reference parameters, yet objects are being changed in ways that I cannot explain.  I have verified function definitions are not pass by reference time and time again.  I have retrieved an object from the DB.  Then I have run an analysis function on that initial object.  I have copied the object to another variable.  Then I run a different analysis function on the copy and not the original.  Running the second analysis function seems to alter the first variable-object. Any ideas on what might be going on here. I have been trying to debug this for hours upon hours and I cannot explain this behavior.  I would prefer not to post the the actual functions as they are proprietary information, however, I can possibly send them privately for some help.   I thank you kindly for your time in trying to help me.

```
//get object from db
$resp= json_decode($ln->getResponseFromDb($resultid)); 

//run pwf analysis function
$resp = $ln->pwfBGCheck($resp);

//show result after pwf
print_r($resp->pwf);

/* shows
* stdClass Object ( [status] => p [reason] => Person has no c record. ) 
*/ 

//copy to another variable
$r2 = $resp;
//run pwf for s record other variable so it is not touching the first one!
$r2 = $ln->pwfBGCheckSexOffender2($r2);
echo '<BR>this is first variable<BR>';
print_r($resp->pwf);
/* copies from second to first for some reason... no pass by reference on this call...       resp variable has not been touched!
* stdClass Object ( [status] => p [reason] => Person has no s record. ) 
*/ 
echo '<BR>this is second<BR>';
print_r($r2->pwf);
/* returns
* stdClass Object ( [status] => p [reason] => Person has no s record. )
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after going crazy forever...
I found this solution:

```
$r2 = unserialize(serialize($resp));
```

I know it is not ideal as there is a performance hit, but I am under a deadline and needed to create a working solution as soon as possible.  I believe that issue remained because even the variables that are being copied are also passed by reference. I am willing to accept another working solution if someone comes up with a better alternative.  Thank you!

also... due to some other issues with serialization (libxml cannot be serialized), this solution didn't work...
but then I thought of

```
$r2 = json_decode(json_encode($resp));
```

and this actually did the trick!

Answer (score 6):

Since PHP5 object always pass by reference. If you want to get copy of object you have to use [clone](https://www.php.net/clone).

[Objects and references](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php#language.oop5.references)

> An exception to the usual assignment by value behaviour within PHP occurs with objects, which are assigned by reference in PHP 5. Objects may be explicitly copied via the clone keyword.

[Assignment Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)

Comment: This is very helpful, however, when I use the clone keyword `$r2 = clone $resp;` I am still yielding the same result.

Comment: `Clone` is clone current object only. If you want to clone properties object too you have to define `__clone` method with: this->_property_object = clone $this->_property_object; Exolore this example: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php#example-224

Answer (score 2):

Also you could use `json_decode($json, true);` (instead of `json_decode($json);`) to get assoc `array` (instead of `stdClass`).

And there would not any issues with references.